# show listview item in a textbox

Tags: c#

there is a listview which stores names from my a textbox and when i select a single name from a row in my listview i want that name to be shown back in my textbox. how can i make it ? there is a people LIst i have stored all the person details

```
    List<person> people = new List<person>();
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
        if(!Directory.Exists(path+"\\AddressBook Data\\"))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path+"\\AddressBook Data\\");
        if(!File.Exists(path+"\\AddressBook Data\\PeopleData.xml"))
            File.Create(path +"\\AddressBook Data\\PeopleData.xml");
    }


    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        person p = new person();
        p.name = textBox1.Text;
        p.email = textBox2.Text;
        p.streetAddress = textBox3.Text;
        p.birthday = dateTimePicker1.Value;
        p.addtionalNote = textBox4.Text;
        people.Add(p);
        listView1.Items.Add(p.name);

        textBox1.Text = "";
        textBox2.Text = "";
        textBox3.Text = "";
        textBox4.Text = "";
        dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

Comment: with the above code it should show the rows one under another, how is it showing now?

Comment: no it is showing in the same row in different columns though i havent made any columns how can i insert a image showing that

Comment: and alos the view settings of the listview control is LargeIcon

Comment: change it to details, it works

Comment: no it is not. i did it once. then the name i entered is not even visible in the listView

Comment: and list view is shown like a box full of space nothing in that is seen. no gridlines

Comment: you need to add atleast one column in form load or before adding items into listview

Comment: if you can watch 3.53 of this video  http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=15&number=172

Comment: but it can even be done without adding columns as in that video

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the `View` of ListView to the `List`.

Add follwoing statements in form_Load:

```
        listView1.View = View.List;
```

Comment: can you please spend 3 minutes watching that video. in that he doesn't use any columns

Comment: @user3304413: got it, Check my edited answer, you need to set View to `List`

Comment: ohhh Thanks alot you saw the video? that guy didnt tell it to set it to list.

Comment: @user3304413: i saw, but he did not start from the beginning of creation of `ListView`, so that i think he might have already set it.

Comment: there are two more vids before that video. but i watched both of them. but he didn't. but there is another problem. i think he has done it in a different way. now i cant get the values i entered back in the textboxes when i select list view items in rows

Comment: @user3304413: better post a new question.

Comment: :can you make this one too